# Meaning of "of" in "the X 'of' Y"

Tags: word-meaning, definition

- engagement: the act **of** engaging : the state **of** being engaged
- redness: the quality or state **of** being red or red-hot
- negotiation: the action or process **of** negotiating or being negotiated

I’ve always wonder what “of” means which is used much in dictionaries in a way positioned like these-quality of ing, act of ing, action of ing, state of ing, event of ing, fact of ing, process of ing etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most appropriate definition that I can find among those supplied by Oxford Dictionaries is:

*expressing the relationship between a general category or type and the thing being specified which belongs to such a category.*

*"the city of Prague"*

In your case, *state or quality* is the general category and *being red* is the thing specified.

Comment: The quality or state of giving out or reflecting light. https://www.lexico.com/definition/brightness Then, shouldn’t it be the action of giving out or reflecting light?

Comment: _Bright_ describes what something is like, not what it does.

Comment: But “giving out” and “reflecting” refer to action.

Comment: The brightness of a light source is a measure of the amount of light it gives out, not a reference to the action of doing so. You are just quibbling about the wording of the dictionary definiton.